CORS configuration for signalr UI client
I have 2 different projects with the following setup: Asp.NET Web API and Asp.NET MVC application.
I want to send signalR notifications from Web API to cshtml package in MVC applications.
[UPDATED]
On the API side I use the following configuration:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSignalR();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "CorsSignalr", policyBuilder =>
        policyBuilder
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(hostName => true));
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.UseCors("CorsSignalr");
app.MapHub<MyHub>("/MyHub");

app.Run();

Notification hub is very simple:
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
}

and I use the below code to send a message:
    await _notificationHub.Clients.All.SendAsync(
        method: "OnReceived",
        arg1: "Message",
        ...

the creating connection in the UI js looks like:
    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
       .withUrl("https://localhost:44000/MyHub")
       .withAutomaticReconnect()
       .build();

NOTE: I don't have any other signalr related configuration in UI other than consumed js library @microsoft/signalr@latest, ie I didn't configure any CORS or didn't add any nuget packages.
all is good. I can send message and receive it in the UI callback. However I don't want storing absolute path to my web api in the JS. How can I remove it?
UPDATE1:
If I remove https://localhost:44000 from the js code and leave only:
    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
       .withUrl("/MyHub")
       .withAutomaticReconnect()
       .build();

I see the below error in the browser (where you can see that signalr tries to find hub in the current to UI address and therefore throw 404 error):
[2024-08-20T10:55:41.570Z] Information: Normalizing '/MyHub' to 'https://localhost:%LOCAL_TO_UI_PORT%/MyHub'.
:%LOCAL_TO_UI_PORT%/MyHub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1:1 
        
        
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()Understand this error
signalr.js:447 [2024-08-20T10:55:41.583Z] Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: : Status code '404' Either this is not a SignalR endpoint or there is a proxy blocking the connection.
log @ signalr.js:447Understand this error
signalr.js:447 [2024-08-20T10:55:41.583Z] Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: : Status code '404' Either this is not a SignalR endpoint or there is a proxy blocking the connection.
log @ signalr.js:447Understand this error
chat.js:31 Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: : Status code '404' Either this is not a SignalR endpoint or there is a proxy blocking the connection.


Do you have app.UseCors("CorsSignalr"); which behind the UseRouting ?

I have UseCors (without UseRouting) on API side and I have nothing on UI (in c#)

Ok, please share more code about your Program, start from var app = builder.Build(); is great.

And please also open the developer tools in browser, and refresh the page, share the error with us, I will guide you fix it asap.

@JasonPan, done

Hi Unnamed, what is %LOCAL_TO_UI_PORT%, you hide it ? or copy from error message directly? And why you think it's cors issue, thanks

LOCAL_TO_UI_PORT it's a PORT where my UI application has been launched (44100 not 44000 where API is launched)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

And why you think it's cors issue - maybe it's not corse issue, because effectively the problem at this point is that I need to say for js side which host to use to receive notification from API

How to determine whether it is a CORS issue.
We will see similar error messages as follows in the console(Browser Developer Tools).

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8181/chat/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

If it's a CORS issue we should check the cors middleware in asp.net core.
In this question, there is an asp.net core mvc application that will use javascript client to connect with signalr server in asp.net core webapi.
In this case, we cannot use a relative path URL (withUrl("/MyHub")) to connect server, because the relative path uses the host address of the current application.
As a common alternative, we can give priority to reading the latest host address from localStorage, so that when the domain name of the webapi changes, there is no need to modify the code in the mvc project, and the latest domain name will be automatically used in the javascript client.
